# Fade out hide only HTML code, JavaScript still running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, three.js

I try to toggle between the different `div` in my `HTML` document. This is my code:

```
    <div id="screen1" class="current">
            <div id="press_any_key_to_continue"> <font style="font-family: verdana" color="yellow">Press Enter to start</font></p> </div>


    <script>
    var container;
    var camera, scene, renderer;

    init();
    animate();
    //And a lot of THREE.js code..

    </script>

    </div>
<div id='screen2'>
<p>Some content goes here</p>
</div>
```

My jQuery method Fade out the `div` which `id` is `screen1` and Fade in another `div` with id `screen2`, like this:

```
$(document).keyup(keyUpHandler);

function keyUpHandler(e) {


    if (e.keyCode == 13) {

        var id = $('.current').attr('id');

        console.log('The id of the current div is: ' + id);
        if (id == 'screen1') {


            toggleDivs('screen2');
        }
    }

}


function toggleDivs(id) {

    console.log('Hello world, the id passed is: ' + id);

    $('.current').fadeOut(600, function () {
        $('#' + id).fadeIn(600);
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        $('#' + id).addClass('current')
    });
}
```

So far so good, screen2 appears with the nice fade in effect, but screen1 doesn't fade out, let's say the html part in screen1 fade out successfully but not the javascript part.

So i assume fadeout doesn't stop a JS script. How can i solve this otherwise. Thanx.

Comment: there is not another `div` in your code (like the `screen2` that you mentioned)

Comment: Hi, i edited my post, please check :)

Answer (score 0):

To stop an animation, you want to use [`.stop`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) however it is not evident in your code that this would be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

The animate() function begins something like a 'background process' and then the rest of the function continues.  This is simply an effect of Javascript works -- since *everything* in the current window freezes while Javascript runs[1], `animate()` sets up a timer that every few milliseconds will do the next bit of animation that needs done.

I don't know the library you are using, but if there is reference to a `callback`, then that means "What function should I call when the animation is finished?"

[1] Yea, yea, Opera, yea yea -- thats the exception

Answer (score 0):

here, fixed your code: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/AK9kZ/

each time you press `enter` it will toggle the `div`.

be aware that there are better ways to accomplish this.

i just reused your code.

[image: um] [image: dois]

Comment: If you try to display something in the script (in your example), it will not be displayed in the screen1 div. That's the issue. Though thanx for the suggestion.

Comment: If there are better ways, could you please suggest one :)

Comment: not sure about what you're trying to say. edit my code and paste the link here so i can try to guess what are you talking about.

Comment: i could suggest one, if only i knew what are you trying to do

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle of what i am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/RASG/AK9kZ/3 I need all that content to follow the `div` screen1 so that when it fade out, it hide all the JS code which belong to that `div`. In other way, how to hide JS script when a div is fade out.

Comment: first, you just copied my link. that is my code. second, what do you mean by **hide JS** ??? there is no such thing!